# How to get the dot product for two embedding layers in tensorflow.keras using the sequential class and set weights for the embedding layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras, dot-product

I'm trying to build a model using `tensorflow.keras` in which I get the dot product of two embedding layers with predefined weights (which I'll optimize when compiling the model). My goal during inference time will be to use `embedding_layer_1` as a lookup table in order to get the weights of the `embedding_layer_1` according to the index specified, which is why I keep `trainable=True`.

The shape of the `weights_matrix` is `(288, 3569)`, and I like to be able to get the dot product of the `embedding_layer_1` (shape is `(288, 3569)`) and the `embedding_layer_2` (shape is `(3569, 288)`). So basically `embedding_layer_2` is the transpose of `embedding_layer_1`.

This is the network:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Embedding, Dot, Flatten

input_dim=288
output_dim=3569

model_1 = Sequential()
embedding_layer_1 = Embedding(input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=output_dim, name='embedding_layer_1', dtype='float64', trainable=True,  input_length=1)
embedding_layer_1.build((None,))
model_1.add(embedding_layer_1)
model_1.layers[0].set_weights([weights_matrix])
model_1.add(Flatten())

model_2 = Sequential()
embedding_layer_2 = Embedding(input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=output_dim, name='embedding_layer_2', dtype='float64', trainable=True,  input_length=1)
embedding_layer_2.build((None,))
model_2.add(embedding_layer_2)
model_2.layers[0].set_weights([role_skill_matrix])
model_2.add(Flatten())

dot_product = Dot(axes=-1)([model_1.output, model_2.output])

model = Sequential([model_1, model_2, dot_product])
model.summary()
```

I get the following error. I tried various changes on the above network such as transposing `embedding_layer_1` and trying to get the dot product of  `embedding_layer_1` and its transposed, as well as other variations yet nothing worked.

I'm using
`tensorflow==2.8.0` and `keras==2.8.0`.

```
    model = Sequential([model_1, model_2, dot_product])
  File "/Users/ayalaallon/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-pipeline/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 629, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ayalaallon/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-pipeline/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/ayalaallon/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml-pipeline/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 178, in add
    raise TypeError('The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. '
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Received: layer=KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='dot/Squeeze:0', description="created by layer 'dot'") of type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you can use layers like the `Dot` layer in a `Sequential` Model. The tricky part is that the layers in a `Sequential` model are stacked.. well, sequentially. How should a layer have more than one input in this type of model, I don't know.
Fortunately, you can just use the `functional` API to construct the Model, and you started to use the functional syntax at the `Dot` layer construction yourself.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Embedding, Dot, Flatten

input_dim=288
output_dim=3569

in1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_dim)
embedding_layer_1 = Embedding(input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=output_dim, name='embedding_layer_1', 
                              dtype='float64', trainable=True,  input_length=1)(in1)
flat1 = Flatten()(embedding_layer_1)

in2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_dim)
embedding_layer_2 = Embedding(input_dim=input_dim, output_dim=output_dim, name='embedding_layer_2',
                              dtype='float64', trainable=True,  input_length=1)(in2)
flat2 = Flatten()(embedding_layer_2)

dot_product = Dot(axes=-1)([flat1, flat2])

model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=[dot_product])
model.summary()
```

Apparently, the model needs the `Input` layer as first layers, without them there is an error with the `Embedding` layers. It runs with the following code without errors:

```py
import numpy as np
model.compile()

x = np.random.rand(100, 288)
model([x, x])
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I ended up using almost the same network as you suggested without using the `Sequential()` class. I also used the `embeddings_initializer` within the `Embedding` layer in order to set the weights of the `Embedding` layer. Your answer helped reach my final solution so I'll mark it as correct.